# Very strange linker errors using matplotlib-cpp, how to even fix it?

Tags: python, c++, xcode, macos, matplotlib

I'm working on C++ project for university (I can't choose Python, my professor decided like so) and I need to use matplotlib-cpp (https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp), I have a macBook with High Sierra 10.13.6 freshly installed and Xcode 10.1, so I did the following:

1. Downloaded the zip from Github, unzipped and placed `matplotlibcpp.h` in my project folder.
2. Got a couple errors about not finding libraries, so i fixed adding `Python/` before `Python/Python.h` and `/usr/local/include/include/` before `numpy/arrayobject.h`. This is what the first lines of the library `matplotlibcpp.h` look like now:

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint> // <cstdint> requires c++11 support
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

#include <Python/Python.h>

#ifndef WITHOUT_NUMPY
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include </usr/local/include/include/numpy/arrayobject.h>
```

3. `#include "matplotlibcpp.h"` and got it to compile and run showing zero errors using `-std=c++17` without adding any specific matplotlib functions, I've done it this way:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"

using namespace std;

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main(...) {
  ...
}
```

4. Now when i add any function such as `plt::plot({1,2,3,4})` it compiles and gives me linker error in clang, it tells me:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyCObject_AsVoidPtr", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyCObject_Type", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyErr_Format", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyErr_Print", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.o
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::import_numpy() in main.o
  "_PyErr_SetString", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::import_numpy() in main.o
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyExc_AttributeError", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyExc_ImportError", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::import_numpy() in main.o
  "_PyExc_RuntimeError", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyFunction_Type", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::safe_import(_object*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
  "_PyImport_Import", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.o
  "_PyImport_ImportModule", referenced from:
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyObject_CallMethod", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.o
  "_PyObject_CallObject", referenced from:
      bool matplotlibcpp::plot<double, double>(std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
  "_PyObject_GetAttrString", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::safe_import(_object*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
      _import_array() in main.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      bool matplotlibcpp::plot<double, double>(std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.o
  "_PyTuple_New", referenced from:
      bool matplotlibcpp::plot<double, double>(std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.o
  "_PyTuple_SetItem", referenced from:
      bool matplotlibcpp::plot<double, double>(std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::~_interpreter() in main.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld /Users/giovannigravili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brain-3.X-hclmildbujzoynbfpgamcnjyrxig/Build/Products/Debug/brain-3.X normal x86_64 (in target: brain-3.X)
    cd /Users/giovannigravili/Documents/GitHub/brain_project/brain-3.X
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.14
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -L/Users/giovannigravili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brain-3.X-hclmildbujzoynbfpgamcnjyrxig/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/giovannigravili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brain-3.X-hclmildbujzoynbfpgamcnjyrxig/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/giovannigravili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brain-3.X-hclmildbujzoynbfpgamcnjyrxig/Build/Intermediates.noindex/brain-3.X.build/Debug/brain-3.X.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/brain-3.X.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/giovannigravili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brain-3.X-hclmildbujzoynbfpgamcnjyrxig/Build/Intermediates.noindex/brain-3.X.build/Debug/brain-3.X.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/brain-3.X_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/giovannigravili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brain-3.X-hclmildbujzoynbfpgamcnjyrxig/Build/Intermediates.noindex/brain-3.X.build/Debug/brain-3.X.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/brain-3.X_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/giovannigravili/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/brain-3.X-hclmildbujzoynbfpgamcnjyrxig/Build/Products/Debug/brain-3.X
```

I got an example compiling through g++ on my terminal using `-I`,`-l` flags, it doesn't run though, it says `ImportError:`. How do I solve this? Thank you kind stranger.

**Edit 1:**

I modified the header referencing to the libraries, Xcode now gives me the same warnings (deprecated `register` use) and error (linker) the compiler does, and now it looks like this,:

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint> // <cstdint> requires c++11 support
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

#include </System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h>

#ifndef WITHOUT_NUMPY
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include </usr/local/include/include/numpy/arrayobject.h>
```

Comment: Did you link to the python library like the directions mentioned here: `g++ basic.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7`

Comment: Maybe you have a different / newer version of python?

Comment: Thank you for your time, what I did and now tried again was `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7`, but it said ```./matplotlibcpp.h:15:10: fatal error: 'Python/Python.h' file not found
#include <Python/Python.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```. I do have Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.8.0, how do I proceed correctly linking it?

Comment: Take a look at the folder structure inside `/usr/include/python2.7` you may have to remove your original fixes. Meaning get rid of the `Python/` prefix you added to the headers.

Comment: Inside `/usr/include/python2.7` I can find all the libraries, including `Python.h`, is there anything else I should look for? I referenced to the library as you said from the file `#include </System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h>` and it correctly reproduces in Xcode the errors terminal compilation gives me, which previously didn't happen, it still gives me the previous error as showed in the post.

Comment: I think there is no `Python` folder inside `/usr/include/python2.7` and you should  revert your initial fix.

Comment: Can you specify what the initial fix was? I'm getting lost, thanks

Comment: In your question you wrote: ***Got a couple errors about not finding libraries, so i fixed adding Python/ before Python/Python.h***